# Resetting Django admin password

Tags: python, django, centos

I am using Django as a virtualenv in CentOs. I am now trying to reset the admin password. I saw many answers in stackoverflow to execute like

```
python manage.py changepassword admin
```

When I execute it, I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: try this command in your virtuelenv  'pip freeze' to be sure that  package was   installed  and try    this python manage.py createsuperuser

Comment: Or you need active you virtualenv

Comment: Hi Levi, Activating the virtualenv worked. Thankyou.

Answer (score -3):

You can create a superuser and the rest is history.

Run the command

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Give the details and you are done.